# About a Corollary of Yoneda's Lemma

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

I am reading Assem-Simson-Skowronski's book "Elements of The Representation Theory of Associative Algebras". I do not understand a Corollary 6.2, (IV. 6.2, Functorial Aproach to almost split). It says that if $F$ is a subfunctor of $Hom_C(-,X)$ then there is a bijection $F(X) \cong Hom\big(Hom_C(-,X),F  \big) $. And then it says that in particular:
$$ Hom_C(X,Y) \cong Hom\big( Hom_C(-,X), Hom_C(-,Y) \big) $$

But this is not true from what he said, unless $Y$ is a subobject of $X$, I do not understand this. Also he uses this claim all over this chapter, so it is crucial.

Comment: $C$ is an additive $k$-category, $X,Y$ are objects in $C$.

Comment: What makes you say it isn't true? Do you have a counterexample? He simply plugged in $Hom_C(-,Y)$ for $F$ in the formula above.

Comment: The first statement is fully general and doesn't require $F$ to be a subfunctor of anything. So is the second statement. (And in particular they're both true.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Qiaochu says in his comment, the existence of the bijections you state is just Yoneda's Lemma (Theorem 6.1 in the book you refer to), regardless of what $F$ is.

But the content of the corollary you refer to (which you haven't stated in full) is that if $F$ is a subfunctor of $\operatorname{Hom}_C(-,X)$ then the bijection sends $f\in F(X)$ to the natural transformation given by composing with $f$. Of course, you're right that $\operatorname{Hom}_C(-,Y)$ need not be a subfunctor of $\operatorname{Hom}_C(-,X)$, and so the second statement isn't strictly a consequence of the first. However, the first statement is true, with exactly the same proof, for $F$ a subfunctor of $\operatorname{Hom}_C(-,Y)$ for any object $Y$, which is probably what the authors of the book meant to say.